# How do I fix the colors of my icons?

Tags: arch-linux, display, theme, icons, appearance

I first noticed an issue I had on Linux Mint using the mate desktop environment. I wasn't able to resolve it, so I thought that switching to a different distro and desktop would be the answer. I'm now using Antergos and the openbox desktop and I've run into the same problem once again.

My icons look weird and are showing the wrong colors. They're displaying as shades of pink, red, and white. I noticed this in several areas such as the app icons in the taskbar, icons in my file manager, icons of programs like GIMP, and the window border theme previews in the LXAppearance settings.

I've tried several things to try to fix or get around this. I've switched to multiple desktop environments and window managers like fluxbox, icewm, awesome, KDE plasma, and gnome. This issue remains in every single DE and WM.

I've also tried changing themes and icon themes and the problem still remains. I'm out of ideas and could really use some help. This has turned my linux desktop into an ugly mess and I really don't want to continue to use it when it's like this. I've included some images of my problem below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDVJA.jpg

Comment: I got the same bug, I noticed it's only affecting Gtk 2 apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by downgrading llvm-libs and clang to 3.9.0-3 (from 3.9.1-1).

[Window decorations and most icons a reddish tone](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=221196)

Comment: Thank you! I downgraded the llvm-libs package and everything is back to normal.